# Linear equation Numerical analysis consistency

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> \begin{align*}
>   x - \alpha y &= 1\\
>   \alpha x - y &= 1
>   \end{align*}

For which values of alpha does the system have an infinite number of solutions, no solutions and one solution.

Find the solution when it is unique.

My attempt:

$-\alpha \cdot \mathrm{eqn}_1 + \mathrm{eqn}_2$ resulting in $(\alpha^2 - 1)y = 1-\alpha$.

then we get $y = (1-\alpha)/(\alpha^2-1)$

so, $y = -1/(1+\alpha)$, but I am trying to proceed

Comment: Is there a second half to your question? It looks like it got cut off mid sentence

Comment: thanks for noticing & editing

Comment: @mary: Note that you can't divide by $\alpha^2 - 1$ if this term is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
x - \alpha y &= 1\\
\alpha x - y &= 1
\end{align*}

By simplifying, we have: 
$$\frac{x-1}{\alpha}=\alpha x-1$$

Which is:

$$(\alpha^2-1)x-(\alpha+1)=0$$

$$x=\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha^2-1}$$

Assuming $\alpha \neq \pm 1$, $x=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ is your unique solution. For $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=-1$ you have many and no solution, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

What you did looks good so far. If every single step you made is legitimate you have found your unique solution: $y=-1/(1+\alpha)$ and $x=1-\alpha/(1+\alpha)$. What do I mean by legitimate? When you are dealing with this kind of exercise what usually "goes wrong" is that you want to divide by $0$ somewhere. You divided by $\alpha^2-1$ at one point, this doesn't work when $\alpha=\pm1$.
What happens in these two cases?